# Partial Isometries: Positivity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Given a unital C*-algebra $1\in\mathcal{A}$.

Then implication holds:
$$J\in\mathcal{A}:\quad JJ^*J=J\implies\sigma(J)\geq0$$

How can I check this?

*(Operator-algebraically?)*

Comment: As a special example, consider a unitary $u$, which certainly satisfies the required relations. However $\sigma(u)\subset S^1$ in general.

Comment: @Phoenix87: Right, so it is far from true..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be true.  Take e.g. the $C^*$ algebra $\mathcal{A} = \mathbb{C}$, the complex numbers.  Then the element $-1$ satisfies 
$$(-1)(-1)^*(-1) = -1$$
but its spectrum (when viewed as an operator) is $\{-1\}$.

Comment: Easy-peasy, thanks! :)